# How to load system-wide daemon on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, unix, launchd

I'm trying to load my daemon-app with this command

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/myPlistFileName
```

It works fine, but only while my user is logged in on system.

How can I load my deamon-app, which will stay loaded without any user logged into the system (like the windows-services)??

The command

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/myPlistFileName
```

give me an error -> *nothing found to load*

Which is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

In order to load the job for everyone you need to run `launchctl` under root privileges. If the job is already loaded under your user account, it won't load using root privileges instead.

Try running `launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/myPlistFileName` first before running `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/myPlistFileName`. Take a look at the output in `system.log` (you can view it using Console.app if you'd prefer) that occurs when you load the daemon.

Comment: Was stuck on this one. Thanks. The man page says the -w clears the Disabled key which has been moved outside the plist.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't seem to run

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/myPlistFileName
```

try to switch to the root user first:

```
sudo su
```

It will ask you for a password - enter your standard user' password, and you will now be using the terminal under the root account.

Than, run the

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/myPlistFileName
```

command.

Answer (score 0):

I was still having issues after trying this. The solution for me was:

```
sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/myPlistFileName
```

After this, I was able to load and unload it as much as I wanted.